# How to find average when instances are grouped or categorized on multiple columns?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

There is a table 'Result' with following data:

```
ID   Title   Category  SubCategory  Value
1    Part-1  CatX      A            100
2    Part-1  CatX      B            0
3    Part-1  CatX      C            50
4    Part-1  CatY      A            100
5    Part-1  CatY      B            0
6    Part-1  CatY      C            100
7    Part-2  CatM      A            30
8    Part-2  CatM      B            10
9    Part-2  CatM      C            100
10   Part-2  CatN      A            50
11   Part-2  CatN      B            10
12   Part-2  CatN      C            80
```

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Title   SubCategory   AvgValue
Part-1  A          100
Part-1  B          0
Part-1  C          75
Part-2  A          40
Part-2  B          10
Part-2  C          90
```

Each Title has 3 SubCategories and I need to display the Average Value of each SubCategory for every Title. Please Help.
Answer can be a SQL server Query or Linq as I can get the Result table in a List/datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try with one another approach as shown below.

```
Create Table Result(Id int, Title Varchar(10), Category Varchar(10), SubCategory Varchar(10), Value Int)
Insert Into Result Values(1, 'Part-1','CatX',      'A',            100),
(2    ,'Part-1','CatX',      'B',            0),
(3    ,'Part-1','CatX',      'C',            50),
(4    ,'Part-1','CatY',      'A',            100),
(5    ,'Part-1','CatY',      'B',            0),
(6    ,'Part-1','CatY',      'C',            100),
(7    ,'Part-2','CatM',      'A',            30),
(8    ,'Part-2','CatM',      'B',            10),
(9    ,'Part-2','CatM',      'C',            100),
(10   ,'Part-2','CatN',      'A',            50),
(11   ,'Part-2','CatN',      'B',            10),
(12   ,'Part-2','CatN',      'C',            80)

Select Title, SubCategory, AVG(Value) as Average from Result
Group By Title, SubCategory

Select Title, SubCategory, SUM(Value) / COUNT(*) as Average
From Result Group By Title, SubCategory
```

The output in both case is as shown below which are same.

[image]

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/SHC11303)

Answer (score 4):

Use `avg()` aggregate function

```
  select Title,SubCategory ,avg(Value) 
  from table_name 
  group by Title,SubCategory
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work

```
select Title, SubCategory, AVG(Value)
from Table1 
group by Title, subcategory
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication97
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SubCategory", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "Part-1", "CatX", "A", 100});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Part-1", "CatX", "B", 0});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "Part-1", "CatX", "C", 50});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, "Part-1", "CatY", "A", 100});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5, "Part-1", "CatY", "B", 0});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {6, "Part-1", "CatY", "C", 100});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {7, "Part-2", "CatM", "A", 30});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {8, "Part-2", "CatM", "B", 10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {9, "Part-2", "CatM", "C", 100});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {10, "Part-2", "CatN", "A", 50});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {11, "Part-2", "CatN", "B", 10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {12, "Part-2", "CatN", "C", 80});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { title = x.Field<string>("Title"), subcategory = x.Field<string>("SubCategory") }).ToList();

            var totals = groups.Select(x => new {title = x.Key.title, subCategory = x.Key.subcategory, average = x.Average(y => y.Field<int>("Value"))}).ToList();

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. ! Is this faster thn stored procedures when data is large?

Comment: When comparing speed between stored procedures and c# there are 3 factors 1)The amount of data transferred between the SQL Server and the c# application.  2) The time of getting the data from database which is the same in both cases.  3) The time for grouping and averaging which depends on Speed of the SQL Server vs the speed of the Local Machine.  The Server could be on the Local Machine and then it is probably very similar times.  In your case you have large amount of data so it probably is faster in a stored procedure.